# django ajax keep appending the same result

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Hello guys i sucessfully create the ajax that update the table without refreshing, but my problem is that the ajax keep appending the same result everytime it run. my question is that how can i fix this so that the ajax only appending the new result to the table instead appending the same result over and over again?

people tell me to use the .html method but i dont think that what i want because if i use this it will change the whole display to the get_more_table.html

destination.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table id="_appendHere" class="table table-striped table-condensed">
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>desc</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
          {% for i in dest %}
             <td>{{ i.name|upper }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.desc|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.status|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.price | capfirst}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
   function updateTable(){
   console.log("hello")
   $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: "get_more_table",
      success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   $("#_appendHere").append(data);
    }
   })
 }
   var interval = setInterval(function () { 
   updateTable(); 
}, 10000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

view

```
def record_table(request):
    dest = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,"destination.html",{'dest':dest})

def get_more_table(request): <--- my callback table
    dest = Destination.objects.all()
    return render(request,"get_more_table.html",{'dest':dest})
```

get_more_table.html

```
          {% for i in dest %}
             <td>{{ i.name|upper }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.desc|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.status|capfirst }}</td>
             <td>{{ i.price | capfirst}}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

thanks everyone for the help i fix this by empty the table and appending it with the data i got from the get_more_table

Answer (score 0):

```
# You can first clear your '_appendHere' id, then append the data by iterating over the response from ajax call

$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url: 'get_more_table',
    success: function (data) {
        $('#_appendHere').empty();
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (key, val) {
            $("#_appendHere").append("\
            <tr>\
            <td>"+val['name']+"</td>\
            <td>"+val['desc']+"</td>\
            <td>"+val['status']+"</td>\
            <td>"+val['price']+"</td>\
            </tr>\
            ");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: when i try this method i got this error TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in my console

Comment: I thought your response data is an object. So now, you have to convert your data into an object. I have updated my answer. You have to change it to $.each(JSON.parse(myData), ...);

Comment: thanks for responding to my problem but i fix it with a little twist on it i will update my code now